# How smart are laptop power bricks for Lenovo Thinkpads?

Tags: power-supply, laptop

I am wondering if there is something "smart" going on inside a standard Lenovo laptop power supply brick (often called “charger”) (X220 and X230 in my case). In other words, is there some negotiation of voltages and current going on like with QC or PD over USB Type C or does the charger simply try to provide as steady a source of 20V as possible and that is all there is to it?  Any kind of communication between the Thinkpad and its power brick?

Comment: The charger I have for the work Lenovo, which has usb C will do nothing for my Mac powerbook that takes usb C...

Comment: Thanks, Solar Mike.  I assume that's different from the X220 and X230 which do not charge via USB-C, though.  USB-C uses power delivery to negotiate voltage, so those chargers are "smart".

Comment: That Lenovo has a usbC charger and no other charging port...

Comment: @SolarMike are you sure that the lenovo charger meets the PD that the Mac wants?

Comment: They are "smart" in a way that if you accidentally short the middle (identification) pin you immediately fry the SuperIO on the motherboard ie. brick your laptop.

Comment: Thanks, George, that is good and important to know.

Answer (score 2):

Those generation chargers with the round or square tips have a resistor that indicates the capacity. It's a 3 pin connector where the pin provides ID.

There is no active negotiation and they only have a single voltage output level.

Nothing like what happens with USB PD or QC

Comment: Thank you for this very useful answer.  Do you know where is that resistor located?  I just opened a dead PSU I had lying around, the cable from the PSU to the Thinkpad has only two wires (B+W).  Am I correct to think that the resistor would be in the tip?

Comment: https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Power_Connector#Signal_Pin documents the resistor and its values

Comment: Yes in the tip.